# EF Core how to add a filter to .ThenIncludes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asqueryable

I'm using EF Core 5.0.4

I have these three entities that have relations.

```cs
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public short ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ParentProp1 { get; set; }
    public string ParentProp2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProcessedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Anniversary { get; set; }

    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public Child()
    {
        Animals = new HashSet<Animals>();
    }

    [Key]
    public short ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Animals> Animals { get; set; }
    //UPDATED TO INCLUDE PARENT
    public Parent Parent {get;set;}
}

public class Animals
{
    [Key]
    public short AnimalId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChildId")]
    public short ChildId { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MAnniversary { get; set; }
    public DateTime PAnniversary { get; set; }

    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository I'm trying to return a List of Parent. How do I add the filter ..see commented code lines... on the IQueryable()?

```cs
public List<Parent> Get(Request request)
{
    var data = _context.Parents
        .Include(r => r.Child)
            .ThenInclude(a => a.Animals)
        .AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();

    data = data.Where(x => x.ProcessedDate == request.ProcessedDate);

    // Here is the filter I'm trying to add but can't because data is an IQueryable() :
    // Animals needs to be filtered based off a query like:
    // data.Child.Animals = data.Child.Animals.Where( d => d.StartDate <= data.ProcessedDate && (
    //                        d.EndDate == null || data.ProcessDate <= d.EndDate
    //                       )
    //                       && d.ChildId == data.ChildId && data.Anniversary >= d.MAnniversary
    //                       ).ToList();

    return data;
}
```

When returning just Parent I'm able to add the filter query like below without any issues because 'data' is not an IQueryable() :

```cs
public Parent Get(int id)
{
    var data = _context.Parents
        .Include(r => r.Child)
            .ThenInclude(a => a.Animals)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentId == id);

    data = data.Where(x => x.ProcessedDate == request.ProcessedDate);

    data.Child.Animals = data.Child.Animals.Where(d => d.StartDate <= data.ProcessedDate && (
                            d.EndDate == null || data.ProcessDate <= d.EndDate
                           )
                           && d.ChildId == data.ChildId && data.Anniversary >= d.MAnniversary
                            ).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

I've tried adding a filter on the .ThenInlude() like below but it doesn't work because I can't access the properties needed.

```cs
var data = _context.Parents
            .Include(r => r.Child)
                .ThenInclude(a => a.Animals.Where(x => x.StartDate <= "this doesn't work because can't access Parent or Child properties")
            .AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();
```

### UPDATE

I added navigation Parent navigation property to Child and changed the query to be based on the inner relations. It looks something like this:

```
var data = _context.Animals
        .Include(r => r.Child)
            .ThenInclude(a => a.Parent)
        .Where(r => r.StartDate <= r.Child.Parent.ProcessedDate && (
                            r.EndDate == null || r.Child.Parent.ProcessDate <= r.EndDate
                           )
                           && r.ChildId == r.Child.Parent.ChildId && 
                 r.Child.Parent.Anniversary >= r.MAnniversary
               ).AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Are you using .net 5? With EF Core 5? Because that was added in .net 5 I believe

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I'm using EF Core 5.0.4 with dotnet Core 3.1.0.

Comment: what do you want to do? Please descrie what you need.

Comment: @zolty13 I'm wanting to add the 'data.Child.Animals.Where(..)' filter to the AsQueryable().

Comment: @ironman And why you cannot do that? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: What about a query based on the inner relation? Like: 
`_context.Children.Include(c => c.Animals.Where(a => /*condition*/ )) .include(c=>c.Parent).where(c=>c.Animals.Count()>0)`

Comment: @atiyar yes, the commented code in the Get(Request request) is what I'm trying to add but can't figure out how to with the .AsQueryable(). The Get(int id) works because it's doing a '.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentId == id);' I'll try to make the question more clear.

Comment: @ironman Thanks. I accidentally deleted my comment  :(

Comment: @atiyar hopefully my edits clarify my question. Basically, I'm trying to add the same filter query to the Get(Request request) that is working on the Get(int id). But because it's using an IQueryable I'm having issues and can't figure out how to add a "complex" filter on the .ThenIncludes.

Comment: @GertArnold correct. Should I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Parent navigation property to Child and changed the query to be based on the inner relations. It looks something like this:

```
var data = _context.Animals
        .Include(r => r.Child)
            .ThenInclude(a => a.Parent)
        .Where(r => r.StartDate <= r.Child.Parent.ProcessedDate && (
                            r.EndDate == null || r.Child.Parent.ProcessDate <= r.EndDate
                           )
                           && r.ChildId == r.Child.Parent.ChildId && 
                 r.Child.Parent.Anniversary >= r.MAnniversary
               ).AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();
```